# How replace string in a file with value of current directory using CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to make another guy's research code reproducible, so that others don't have the same trouble I'm having right now. But, I'm lacking the experience with cmake for that. Here is what I could do after reading the docs:
In the same folder as my `CMakeLists.txt` I have a file called `io_utils.h` with a `ROOT_PATH` variable whose value is `VALUE_ROOT_PATH`.
I want to replace that string with the value of the file's current directory. So I tried to add the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Set ROOT_PATH in io_utils.h
FIND_PATH(BUILD_PATH CMakeLists.txt . )
FILE(READ ${BUILD_PATH}io_utils.h IO_UTILS)
STRING(REGEX REPLACE "VALUE_ROOT_PATH" "${BUILD_PATH}" MOD_IO_UTILS "${IO_UTILS}" )
FILE(WRITE ${BUILD_PATH}io_utils.h "${MOD_IO_UTILS}")
```

I tried to make and install that but it is not working, the file isn't changed. What's wrong with what I did?

Answer (score 21):

I suggest a different approach using the `configure_file` cmake macro. First, you create a template file that references any variables you plan to set in cmake, then the macro substitutes the actual value in place of the variable. For example, let's say we have a template file `io_utils.h.in` that looks something like this:

```
const char* ROOT_PATH = "${BUILD_PATH}";
```

In your `CMakeLists.txt`, you can do something like this:

```
configure_file( io_utils.h.in io_utils.h )
```

When you run `cmake`, it will use the first file as a template (`io_utils.h.in` here) to generate the second file (called `io_utils.h` here) with the value substituted in:

```
const char* ROOT_PATH = "/path/to/CMakeLists.txt";
```

By the way, CMake has a built-in variable that references the directory with the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` called `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`. Try replacing `BUILD_PATH` above with this variable.

Comment: Since not all files are headers which you may want to search/replace, it would still be interesting to have an answer to the original question, as well as this suggested alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it seems to be a lot easier to define a macro and let the preprocessor do the job:

`add_definition(ROOT_PATH ${VALUE_ROOT_PATH})`

Comment: This has the disadvantage that the file becomes dependent on the define from the build environment. For instance, a header in a library that you want to ship to clients probably should be self-contained and not have such a dependency. But if that is of no concern, this is a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22293945/23715) by @atsui is fine for most cases and his approach should probably be used by default. But sometimes you may already have some ini-file that you want to edit according to your needs, and you don't want to create and support a template just to be able to use `configure_file` command.

For such cases the approach from OP may work as well. Actually, the code in the question is almost working. I only needed to add a path separator between `${BUILD_PATH}` and `io_utils.h`, i.g. it should be `${BUILD_PATH}/io_utils.h` in both `file` commands.

There are several things to note about this code, though:

1. The code edits the file in source tree. Generally, [out-of-source](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Getting%20Started.html#directory-structure) builds should be preferred, since they have many pros over the in-source builds. For out-of-source version, [CMAKE_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html) variable may be useful.
2. `string(REGEX REPLACE ...)` is used, but in this case `string(REPLACE ...)` may be enough.
3. You may actually use the same variable as input and as output in `string(REGEX REPLACE ...)` and `string(REPLACE ...)`.
4. Please note, that `file(WRITE ...` may change line ending type, if line endings do not correspond to host system. If this is not acceptable, then `file(GENERATE ... CONTENT ... NEWLINE_STYLE ...)` may be used instead (but it requires at least CMake 3.20).
5. Don't forget about the double quotes around the content variable value, otherwise you will [lose your semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72098319/23715).

Having all this, below is just another example of how to edit file in CMake.

```
file(READ "${SOURCE_DIR}/file.ini" FILE_CONTENT)
string(REPLACE "one" "two" FILE_CONTENT "${FILE_CONTENT}" )
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/file.ini" "${FILE_CONTENT}")
install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/file.ini" DESTINATION etc)
```